# Free-fall air resistance problem

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, physics

I´m working on a free fall problem and I got an equation with variable $k$ when the situation has air resistance. Then I compared with no air resistance equation ($-4.9$, considering t variable).
So, I got this:

```
113.68t/k + (1345.6/(k^2))*(1 - Exp^(-kt/11.6)) == -4.9t^2
```

I tried `NSolve`, `DSolve`, `NDSolve` to find the solutions of $k$, but none of them could answer it.

Until now i got this

```
 y := -4.9 t^2
a = Plot[113.68t/k-(1345.6/(k^2))*(1-e^(-k*t/11.6))= -4.9 t^2, {t, 0, 1.4}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green]
teorico = Plot[y, {t, 0, 1.4}];
Show[teorico, a, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: You have several syntactic errors, such as `Exp^(...)` instead of `Exp[...]`, `-4,9` instead of `-4.9`.  But your fundamental problem is that your equation must be incorrect, since there is no solution.

Comment: Note that `DSolve` and `NDSolve` are for solving _differential_ equations (either analytically or numerically.)  One wouldn't expect them to be of any help here.

Comment: That's a different equation;  there's probably a solution to this one.  (Your original one had a minus sign on the second term.)  However, your equation still has the syntax problems pointed out by @DavidG.Stork concerning the exponential function.

Comment: Put your cursor on `Exp` and push `F1` .  You managed to invent two different incorrect expression syntaxes for the exponential.

Answer (score 4):

The corrected equation can be solved using `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[(113.68 t/k - (1345.6/(k^2))*(1 - Exp[-k*t/11.6]) == -4.9 t^2) /. t -> 1, {k, 0.5}]
(* {k -> 0.235142} *)
```

This solves the equation for the value of $k$ corresponding to $t$ = 1 second.  `FindRoot` requires an initial "guess" for the value of $k$;  in this case, I've used $k = 0.5$.

Other choices of $t$ will yield different values of $k$.  In fact, your equation reduces to $kt = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the root of the equation
$$
113.68/\alpha - (1345.6/(\alpha^2))*(1 - e^{-\alpha/11.6}) = -4.9
$$
which, as noted above, yields $\alpha \approx 0.235142$.  For a given value of $t$, $k$ will then be equal to $\alpha/t$.

---

For the original equation (with a minus sign on the second term), no solution exists.  We note from the form of the equation that the left-hand side will be strictly positive for positive values of $k$;  so if the left-hand side is equal to -4.9, then we must have $k <0$.  But if we run

```
FindMaximum[{113.68/k + (1345.6/(k^2))*(1 - Exp[-k/11.6]), k < 0}, k]
```

we obtain

```
(* {-20.8733, {k -> -22.9611}} *)
```

and so the function never attains a value greater than -20.8733 for any negative value of $k$.

If you don't believe me, here's the graph:

```
Plot[113.68/k + (1345.6/(k^2))*(1 - Exp[-k/11.6]), {k, -100, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note the correct form of the exponential function in my code, as was pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

There is no solution to your equation. If you specify `Reals` for k Mathematica outputs an empty list as solution:

```
NSolve[113.68/k + 1345.6/k^2*(1 - Exp[-k/11.6]) == -4.9, k, Reals]
(*{}*)
```

If you plot the righ and left hand side of the equation they don't cut each other:

```
Plot[{113.68/k + 1345.6/k^2*(1 - Exp[-k/11.6]), -4.9}, {k, -60, 60}]
```

[image]